# Reference a newly created object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to get the id of an object after creating it, like so:

```
 post = Post.create_with_data(data)
 post_id = post.id #id of the post object just created in previous line
```

However, post_id is `nil`. How do I achieve my goal? I don't want to use `Post.last`, because it might create data conflict when multiple users trying to create post at the same time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `create_with_data` do you `save` the object?  The `id` is nil until it's been saved.

Comment: Yes, I do save the object. I'll look into it to see why I don't get the id back.

Comment: Are you checking to make sure the save is valid? If `save` doesn't return `true` id will be nil.

Comment: Thanks Richard. It turns out my `create_with_data` only creates but does not save the object.

Comment: @RichardBrown, while saving will indeed commit a new object to the database, it (by itself) will not return the new object from the function. In order for the code cited in the question to work, the object must be returned after it's saved.

Comment: @zeantsoi true, I assumed his method would return the newly minted (and saved) object.

Answer (score 2):

Rails functions return the last evaluated statement. If you're going to write your own `create_with_data` model method, you'll want to return the actual object. `object.save` with return either `true` or `false`, but not the object itself.

In order to return the object (and thus access its id in the manner specified), just express the object itself as the last statement of your function and it will automatically be returned when you call the method.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.create_with_data(data)
    photo = self.new(data)
    photo.save
    photo # returns the photo object
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
post = Post.create!({attribute: 'value'})
post_id = post.id
```

I'm not sure what the method `create_with_data` does, but it doesn't seem to save your post.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def data=(data)
    # ... use data here
  end
end

Post.create(data: data)
```

It's much cleaner and it will call save for you! Your error is because create_with_data is not persisting the object (not saving, failing a validation when saving, etc.)